# PL/SQL function help in returning total numbers

Tags: function, plsql

This is my code.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION estimated_hours (sno NUMBER)
RETURN NUMBER IS
return_var NUMBER;
BEGIN
SELECT COUNT (*)
FROM task 
WHERE planned_start_date > change_date

GROUP BY stage_id


RETURN return_var;
END;
/
```

i am new to database and i dont know what am doing wrong. im trying to calculate and return the total of estimated hours in a given stage before changes where made to the hours.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the result of the select somewhere:

```
SELECT COUNT (*)
   INTO return_var -- you are missing this
FROM task 
WHERE planned_start_date > change_date
GROUP BY stage_id; -- and you are missing the statement terminator ; here
```

You should go through the PL/SQL manual to learn more details about this: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/static.htm#LNPLS006

Comment: Probably don't want the group by as it could return multiple rows, I'd think.

Comment: @DavidAldridge: obviously, yes. Thanks for the hint